# Date comparison not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have the following if then statement in my JS code.

```
    if (attributes.DATE > '10/20/2013'){
        html += '<b>Maximum percentage:</b> ' + aPerc + '%';
    }
    else {
        html += '<b>Percentage:</b> ' + aPerc + '%';    
    }
```

It seems to be working fine for October 2013 dates, and all January dates (no matter the year).

For past October years, it will display "Maximum percentage:" for Oct. 1-19 and "Percentage" for Oct. 20-31st.

It does not work correctly for other months. E.g. Feb, March, April, etc. it displays "Maximum Percentage".

I am guessing it has something to do with my date format? Thank you.

Comment: I think you're comparing strings, not dates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this:

```
var date1 = new Date(attributes.DATE);
var date2 = new Date('10/20/2013');

if (date1 > date2){
    html += '<b>Maximum percentage:</b> ' + aPerc + '%';
}
else {
    html += '<b>Percentage:</b> ' + aPerc + '%';    
}
```

That way, you're comparing two *date* objects rather than two *string* objects.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a *string* comparison, but the order of the fields in the string will not give you a date-order comparison. (You'd get one if both strings were in `yyyy/MM/dd` order...)

If `DATE` is a `Date` instance, you can do this:

```
if (attributes.DATE >= new Date(2013, 9, 21)){
```

...which will be true from midnight on October 21st (the month value starts with 0 = January, so 9 = October). Note I made it `>=` and the 21st rather than the 20th, because I assumed if you're looking for something `> '10/20/2013'`, you mean the 21st or later (as opposed to meaning "any time after midnight on the 20th").